# Is the double assignment/if predicate possible? c

Tags: c

can you tell me please if the next code can work and what is the meaning of it? I'm talking about the line: if((a=b=c)) 
st - a struct that was defined.

```
st* a;
st* b;
st* c;
. // build the struct c correctly with malloc etc
.
.
if((a=b=c)) - the line
```

Is there a double assignment of the struct c into a and b (shallow copy ?)

Thank you

Comment: Please don't write unreadable code for the sake of it. A better way to write this would be: `a=c; b=c; if(c != NULL)`.

Comment: Yes, but I found this code and I did not understand it. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

b=c returns the value of b (after c is assigned), which is assigned to a. They're pointers so it's only copying the 4 or 8 bytes for that, not the struct.

Comment: The whole expression evaluates in the end to the value c had prior to the expression, which is true, if the pointer was not 0 in the first place.

Comment: @meandbug Sure, but the assignments happen nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

The mean of this code line is rather simple but overall I would say useless (no offense of this).

What happens is:

b (as pointer) points to the same memory location of c, a (as pointer) points to the same memory location of b (and hence c)

if c was null, then it would return false.

I would say that it is like saying

if (c != 0)

in terms of logical condition with the addition of the assignment of the pointers a and b.

Comment: Thank you, it can be used when I want to assign the head and the tail of a link list for the first time and do something while c!=0